# OpenTracing in .NET core without taking dependency on specific solution library

Tags: .net-core, microservices, opentracing, 12factor, jaeger

For logging in our microservice applications we simply log to stdout/console and the docker logging driver handles and redirects these logs somewhere e.g. gelf/logstash, fluentd, etc. Basically, we're following [12 factor](https://12factor.net/logs) guidelines for logging. This means that developers working on the application code don't need to know anything about the underlying logging solution (e.g. Elasticsearch, Graylog, Splunk, etc) - it's entirely an ops/configuration concern. In theory we should be able to change the underlying logging solution without any code changes.

I'd like something similar for traces and my research has led me to OpenTracing. Developers shouldn't need to know the underlying tracing solution (e.g. Jaeger, Zipkin, Elastic APM, etc) and as per logging; in theory we should be able to change the underlying tracing solution without any code changes.

I've successfully got a .NET core POC sending traces to Jaeger using the [opentracing/opentracing-csharp](https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing-csharp) and [jaegertracing/jaeger-client-csharp](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-csharp) libraries.

I'm still trying to fully get my head around OpenTracing, but I'm wondering if there's a way to send traces to an OpenTracing compliant API without having to take a hard dependency on a particular solution such as Jaeger (i.e. the jaeger-client-csharp library). Based on my understanding OpenTracing is just a standard. Shouldn't I just be able to configure an OpenTracing endpoint with some sampling options without needing the jaeger-client-csharp library? Or is it that the jaeger-client-csharp is not actually Jaeger specific and can actually send traces to any OpenTracing API?

Example configuration shown below, which uses jaeger client library:

```
services.AddOpenTracing();

if (appSettings.TracerEnabled)
{
   services.AddSingleton(serviceProvider =>
   {
      var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
      var config = Jaeger.Configuration.FromEnv(loggerFactory);

      var tracer = config.GetTracer();

      GlobalTracer.Register(tracer);

      return tracer;
   });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OpenTracing](https://opentracing.io/specification/) [is a set of standard APIs that consistently model and describe the behavior of distributed systems](https://github.com/opentracing/specification/blob/master/project_organization.md))

OpenTracing did not describe how to collect, report, store or represent the data of interrelated traces and spans. It is implementation details (such as [jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io/) or [wavefront](https://www.wavefront.com/)).

jaeger-client-csharp is very jaeger-specific. But there is one exception, called [zipkin](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.12/features/#backwards-compatibility-with-zipkin) which in turns is not fully OpenTracing compliant, even it has similar terms.

If you are OK with [opentracing-contrib/csharp-netcore](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/csharp-netcore/) (hope you are using this library) then if you want to achieve "no code change" (in target microservice) in order to configure tracing subsystem, you should use some plug-in model.

Good news that aspnetcore has concept of [hosted startup assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ASPNET/Core/fundamentals/host/platform-specific-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2), which allow you to configure tracing system. So, you can have some library called `JaegerStartup` where you will implement IHostedStartup like follows:

```
public class JaegerStartup : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices((ctx, services) =>
        {
            services.AddOpenTracing();

            if (ctx.Configuration.IsTracerEnabled()) // implement it by observing your section in configuration.
            {
                services.AddSingleton(serviceProvider =>
                {
                    var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
                    var config = Jaeger.Configuration.FromEnv(loggerFactory);

                    var tracer = config.GetTracer();

                    GlobalTracer.Register(tracer);

                    return tracer;
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When you decide to switch the tracing system - you need to create another library, which can be loaded automatically, and target microservice code will not be touched.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. The IHostingStartup is a better approach than what I've currently got - reminds me a bit of MEF. Ultimately I'd like to be able to switch between Open-Tracing/Telemetry compliant tracers (e.g. ElasticAPM, Jaeger, etc) with just config. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the IHostingStartup approach would still require a re-compilation (or at least a rebuild of the docker image). Ideally changing the tracer would be an OPS concern.

Comment: Also; yes - using opentracing-contrib/csharp-netcore library :) 
I guess what I would have liked is some standardisation for the *reporting* API. This would mean that you could use whatever (OT compliant) client-library/agent you want e.g. elastic/apm-agent-dotnet and the underlying tracer solution could be something else e.g. Datadog or Wavefront, etc. I suspect OpenTracing is not at this level of maturity, or is not attempting to solve this problem...

Comment: You do not need to re-compile or rebuild. You need to create new separate library (only here you need to compile) which contains injection logic for new tracer. When you will have new library, OPS guys will grab new lib and change the [environment variable called ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ASPNET/Core/fundamentals/host/platform-specific-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2#specify-the-hosting-startup-assembly). Reporting API is implementation detail. You should use DiagnosticsSource OR ITracer directly for traces and spans to be collected and reported.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be updated that now we have Opentelemtry dirrect supported by ELastic APM server and also nativ support in NetCore Activity class..

```
public static partial class ServiceExtension {

        public static IServiceCollection AddTelemerty(
            this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
            IConfiguration Configuration, IWebHostEnvironment Environment) {

            serviceCollection.AddOpenTelemetryTracing((builder) => {
                // Sources
                builder.AddSource(Sources.DemoSource.Name);

                builder.SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder
                  .CreateDefault()
                    //.AddAttributes( new List<KeyValuePair<String, object>> { 
                    //   new KeyValuePair<String, object>("SomeKey", "This is String Value")
                    //  })
                  .AddService(Environment.ApplicationName));

                builder.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation(opts => {
                    opts.RecordException = true;
                });

                builder.AddElasticsearchClientInstrumentation();

                builder.AddSqlClientInstrumentation();

                builder.AddHttpClientInstrumentation(opts => opts.RecordException = true);

                if (Uri.TryCreate(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Jaeger"), UriKind.Absolute, out var uri)) {
                    builder.AddJaegerExporter(opts => {
                        opts.AgentHost = uri.Host;
                        opts.AgentPort = uri.Port;
                        opts.BatchExportProcessorOptions = new OpenTelemetry.BatchExportProcessorOptions<Activity>() {
                        };
                    });
                
                    // builder.AddZipkinExporter(opts => {
                    //     opts.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:9412/api/v2/spans");
                    // });
                }
            });

            return serviceCollection;
        }
    }
```